# How can I position a tikz matrix to the side of a Venn diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I have a `tikzpicture` that consists of a Venn diagram, with a matrix for the legend. However, I can't find any documentation on how to position the matrix to the side of the diagram instead of on top of it. Any advice?

```
\begin{center}                 
  \begin{tikzpicture}[         
  1/.style={shape=rectangle, pattern=north east lines},
  2/.style={shape=rectangle, pattern=north west lines},
  3/.style={shape=rectangle, pattern=vertical lines},
  4/.style={shape=rectangle, pattern=dots}
  ]                            
    \begin{scope}[blend group=soft light]
      \fill[1] (135:1) circle (2);
      \fill[2] ( 45:1) circle (2);
      \fill[3] (-90:1) circle (2);
    \end{scope}                
    \matrix [draw,below left] at (current bounding box.north east) {
      \node [1,label=right:1] {}; \\
      \node [2,label=right:2] {}; \\
      \node [3,label=right:3] {}; \\
      \node [4,label=right:4] {}; \\
    };                         
  \end{tikzpicture}            
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `positioning` library to place the matrix right of the Venn diagram, which you can put in a `local bounding box`. This snippet puts the legend right of the diagram, but obviously you can use left or above or below, and use additional shifts etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,positioning,matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}                 
  \begin{tikzpicture}[         
  1/.style={pattern=north east lines},
  2/.style={pattern=north west lines},
  3/.style={pattern=vertical lines},
  4/.style={pattern=dots}
  ]                            
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=venn]
      \fill[1] (135:1) circle[radius=2];
      \fill[2] ( 45:1) circle[radius=2];
      \fill[3] (-90:1) circle[radius=2];
    \end{scope}                
    \matrix [draw,right=1em of venn]  {
      \node [1,label=right:1] {}; \\
      \node [2,label=right:2] {}; \\
      \node [3,label=right:3] {}; \\
      \node [4,label=right:4] {}; \\
    };                         
  \end{tikzpicture}            
\end{center} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you!